# In python, when I call a function from another script I get a NameError?

Tags: python, function

I think I am making a very basic mistake but I can't seem to figure it out. The error is mentioned below but I am confused because `wb` is defined in `open_xl_file()`:

When I try to call the functions from another script

```
import openpyxl
import os
import re

def open_xl_file():
    loc = input("Please enter path of the file:")
    os.chdir(loc)
    file = input("Filename:")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

def sheet_select():
    check = input("Have you called open_xl_file? If yes Press 1 else press 2: ")
    print(check)
    if int(check) != 1:
        open_xl_file()
        sheet = input("Which Sheet do you want to email?\n")
        wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        sheet
    else:
        sheet = input("Which State do you want to email?\n")
        wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        sheet
```

Error log:

> NameError: name 'wb' is not defined.

Comment: Reading about scope of variables in python might help. Refer [here](http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.in/2012/05/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the open workbook with in `open_xl_file`: `return openpyxl.load_workbook(file)` and make a reference to `wb` in `sheet_select`: `wb = open_xl_file()`:

```
import re, openpyxl, os


def open_xl_file():
    loc = input("Please enter path of the file:")
    os.chdir(loc)
    file = input("Filename:")
    return openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

def sheet_select():
    check = input("Have you called open_xl_file? If yes Press 1 else press 2: ")
    print(check)
    wb = open_xl_file()
    if int(check) != 1:
        sheet = input("Which Sheet do you want to email?\n")
        wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        return sheet
    else:
        sheet = input("Which State do you want to email?\n")
        wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        return sheet
```

Comment: Ah yes. Completely forgot what I read about `print` and `return` difference and uses. :)

Comment: Slight problem with this. It makes the `if` pointless? Basically no matter what the input the `open_xl_file()` will be executed because `wb` is mentioned in both.

Comment: Yes, if you want to access `wb`, you have to open the workbook. So your `if` and `else` do exactly the same. What should be the difference between both?

Comment: Gave it a hard thought, and you are absolutely right. I wanted to check if `open_xl_file()` had been called and based on that remove the need to `input` `file` and `path`. This would in turn make me call all the functions in the next function. Example: if I want to `def change_xl_file`  I would need to call the `sheet_select` function to get working on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that variable *wb* is defined in scope of open_xl_file() function, i.e. is visible only inside this function ("local" variable). So if you want to use it outside that function you should either make it global (which is highly not recommended), or return it from your function

Answer (score 0):

'wb' is not defined in function 'sheet_select', you need to pass 'wb' to sheet_select. You could try:

```
def open_xl_file():
    loc = input("Please enter path of the file:")
    os.chdir(loc)
    file = input("Filename:")
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    return wb

def sheet_select(wb):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myWb = open_xl_file()
    sheet_select(myWb)
```